# Retrieving the text of a custom listview from textview

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have the following code which displays a menu if long pressed on a listview:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    if (v.getId()==R.id.lvFiles) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
        menu.setHeaderTitle("What would you like to do?");
        String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menuSelect); 
        for (int i = 0; i<menuItems.length; i++) {
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems[i]);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
    int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId();
    String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menuSelect);
    String menuItemName = menuItems[menuItemIndex];

    TextView ck = (TextView) mFrame4.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.format("Selected %s and %s", menuItemName, ck.getText().toString()), 2000).show();
    return true;
}
```

My custom listview calls another layout which has a textview. How do i display the value of the text of the selected list from the listview?

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.format("Selected %s and %s", menuItemName, DISPLAY THE TEXT OF THE SELECTED TEXTVIEW, 2000).show();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get Text of `TextView` using following code:

```
String txt = ((TextView) info.targetView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: what would be the best way to refresh my listview? I have the context menu to delete a file. Once it's deleted, I want to refresh the listview. I looked at some of the tutorials, wasn't too clear.

Comment: @ZahidH If you update your adapter after deleting the file, then `adapater.notifyDataSetChanged();` will tell the `ListView` that its data has been changed, but if you do not update your adapter, the best way is to simply call the method that feeds your adapter.

Comment: If I use the following line: `getActivity().getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(1);` which switches to a different tab after I perform some action on my listview and come back to the tab with the listview it updates. How do I achieve the tab switch action without switching the tab itself?

Comment: When you want to populate a `ListView`, first you fetch data from somewhere, then you feed this data to an `Adapter`, and after that you attach the adapter to the `ListView` and it will show the data. Just enclose this steps in a `Method` and call that method whenever you need to update `ListView`